# How to split files according first column awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I show example what I need to do:

**INPUT:**

```
name value1 value2 value3
john xxxxx yyyyy qqqqqq
john xxxxx ddddd vvvvvv
john mmmmm jjjjj llllll
paul xxxxx yyyyy qqqqqq
paul ccccc ccccc dddddd
```

and I need to keep header and split into files according **same** name in first column. **I need to keep naming my output files according first column.**

**Output:**

*FILE1*: john.tsv

```
name value1 value2 value3
john xxxxx yyyyy qqqqqq
john xxxxx ddddd vvvvvv
john mmmmm jjjjj llllll
```

*FILE2*: paul.tsv

```
name value1 value2 value3
paul xxxxx yyyyy qqqqqq
paul ccccc ccccc dddddd
```

INPUT and OUTPUT file is tab separate. Header is always same.

My solution is very complicated and slow:

```
head -1 INPUT > header

awk 'NR>1{print $1}' | sort | uniq > names

while read line

 do grep $line INPUT | cat header - > $line.tsv

< names

done
```

Comment: are they sorted? for ex: all `john` entries are always next to each other?

Comment: Yeas always are sorted by name.

Comment: better to edit the question with sorting requirement and also change sample input and expected output to reflect sorting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the answers posted so far have issues that would make them fragile and/or non-portable (e.g. use of getline without checking it's result, unparenthesized right side of output redirection, use of gawk-specific features, and not closing each output file when done with it) and/or unnecessarily complicated.

To sort your input file by the first 2 columns while retaining the header is:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>1), $0}' file | sort | cut -f2-
name value1 value2 value3
john mmmmm jjjjj llllll
john xxxxx ddddd vvvvvv
john xxxxx yyyyy qqqqqq
paul ccccc ccccc dddddd
paul xxxxx yyyyy qqqqqq
```

and to robustly, portably, efficiently print your input including the header line to separate files named based on the first column is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 { hdr=$0; next }
$1 != prev {
    close(out)
    out = $1 ".tsv"
    print hdr > out
    prev = $1
}
{ print > out }
```

So to put it all together would be:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>1), $0}' file | sort | cut -f2- | awk -f tst.awk
```

Comment: Ed thank you for nice solution. Would be possible please to use your awk code like one liner in termina? I am try to use:  awk 'NR==1 {hdr=$0; next }$1 != prev {close(out) out=$1 ".csv" print hdr > out prev = $1} {print>out}' infile. But it does not work.

Comment: Of course, just replace every newline with a `;` except the one immediately after `{`.

Comment: @EdMorton Ed your knowledge of awk is amazing. Thank you for your sharing your experiences.

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk` we can write something like,

```
$ awk 'NR == 1{header = $0; next} 
    !($1 in filename){ print header > ($1".tsv") } 
    NR > 1 { print $0 > ($1".tsv"); filename[$1] }' file
```

**What it does?**

- `NR == 1{header = $0}` If number of records read is `1`, this is the header, save it in `header` for later usage.
- `NR > 1 { print $0 > ($1".tsv"); filename[$1] }` If we have read more than one record already, print the content of the line to file name `$1`, ie the first column.

  - `filename[$1]` We are saving the filename in an associative array indexed by the filename. This array is used to print out the header.
- `($1 in filename){ print header > ($1".tsv") }` If we cannot find the current filename in `filename` array, it is the first occurrence. So we print out the header into the file.

---

**Edit**

If you want to sort the files on the second column, then we can sort them first and then pipe them to `awk` like,

```
$ sort -n -k2 file | awk ....
```

- `-n` Numeric sort.
- `-k2` sort on second key.

This **may not work**, if the header is also numeric.

Comment: suggest `awk 'NR == 1{header = $0; next} !($1 in filename){ print header > $1".tsv" } { print $0 > $1".tsv"; filename[$1] }'` to avoid file creation for header as well to match file extension expected by OP

Comment: You copied the answer I have not yet posted!

Comment: @nu11p01n73R thats awesome solution and very fast. It is possible sort data according second column before I add header? Thank you so much for elegant solution!!!!

Comment: @Paul That wouldn't be straight forward, because from awk perspective it just read lines and output them. What we can do is sort it first using `sort` command then pipe the result to the awk script.

Comment: @JamesBrown Yes, If the header is also numeric.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Thank you so much. This helps very well. I am very appreciate your time spending this kind of "problem" :)

Comment: ... or the field values are not numeric.

Comment: Output redirection to an unparenthesized expression is undefined behavior per POSIX so YMMV with what individual awks will do with it. You should also close each output file as you go so you don't hit the "too many open files" error if the input file is reasonably large.

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry, I didn't get the first point about unparanthesized expression. About the closing, it was new to me, I think I need not edit my answer as you have added a better solution. Thank you.

Comment: When you write `print > $1 ".tsv"` any awk implementation is allowed to treat that as `print > ($1 ".tsv")` as you intended but since an unparenthsized expression on the right side of output redirection is undefined by POSIX they can (and some do) alternatively treat it as `(print > $1) ".tsv"` and produce a syntax error. To be POSIX compliant and avoid relying on how any given awk implements undefined behavior you must always parenthesize any expression on the right side of output redirection: `print > ($1".txt")`.

Comment: @EdMorton ohh, ok. I have corrected my answer. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

similar to @nu11p01n73R's answer, added sorting of the data portion in the script

```
$ awk 'NR==1{h=$0; next}
    !p[$1]++{print h > $1} 
            {print | "sort -k2 >> " $1}' file

$ head paul john

==> paul <==
name value1 value2 value3
paul ccccc ccccc dddddd
paul xxxxx yyyyy qqqqqq

==> john <==
name value1 value2 value3
john mmmmm jjjjj llllll
john xxxxx ddddd vvvvvv
john xxxxx yyyyy qqqqqq
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I have this error message: NR==1{h=$0; next}!p[$1]++ {print h > $1}{print | "sort -k2 >>" >>>  $ <<< 1}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1  - any idea?

Comment: is your script in single quotes like I posted?

Comment: Unparenthesized output redirection is undefined behavior per POSIX so that may be what's causing the OPs syntax error. $1 might contain blanks so you need to quote it. You may need to close() the pipe when switching output files.